# source bash script automatically when new shell created

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have bash script within which some function are declared and I like to source it automatically when a new shell created so that I can use the functions immediately. Add a `source ~/setsetup.sh` in the `~/.bashrc` seems do not work.

EDIT:
Both ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc works. I just have a stupid typo when source the script. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your `.bashrc` is being sourced?

Comment: Try using . rather than source. For instance `. setsetup.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the new shell you create is a login shell, it will execute one of `.bash_login`, `.bash_profile`, or `.profile` (whichever it finds first) instead of `.bashrc`. Typically, you source `.bashrc` from one of the two `bash` specific ones if you use them. You should not put any `bash`-specific commands in `.profile`, as that file may be read by other non-`bash` shells. For example, if you decide to source your script from `.profile`, you should use the `. setsetup.sh` form, and make sure that nothing `bash` specific is in that script.

Comment: any difference between `source setup.sh` or `. setup.sh`

Comment: `.` is the name of the command in the POSIX standard, which doesn't include the synonym `source`. If you shell supports `source`, there is no difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

There are several files. The relevant one is likely `~/.profile` for your case. It is often used to source `.bashrc`.

Check `man .profile` for details. When `bash` is started as login shell `.profile` is relevant, otherwise `.bashrc`.

Comment: Haha +1 for jinx! Highfive! ;)

Comment: Yours is the better answer. :)

Comment: both ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc works. I just have a stupid typo when source the script.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `~/.profile` which *should* execute every time you create a new bash shell.